# How to use JFrog Artifactory to proxy GitHub as Go Repository?

Tags: go, artifactory

I want to use Go Remote repository caching/proxying Github. 
I have created Go remote repo `github` proxying `https://github.com/` (Credentials added as mentioned in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Go+Registry#GoRegistry-RemoteRepositories).

When I run `go get` artifactory log shows following error:

````
2019-05-29 16:01:29,586 [http-nio-8081-exec-252] [ERROR] (o.a.a.g.r.GoResource:88) - Unsupported go repository request for 'github'```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Artifactory Go repositories, you can't resolve from a remote repository directly, packages has to be resolved from a virtual repo.
Just include it in any Go virtual repository and you should be good to go.

Also, why not use gocenter for Go packages? It's much more reliable IMO.

Comment: some of the packages are not available in GoCenter and also we have some private packages that we want to use from GitHub Ent and BitBucket.

Comment: Also I tried resolving packages from Virtual repo I get same error.

Comment: Unsupported repository request means Artifactory can't find that go repo. It has to be local or virtual. What have you used for your goproxy?

Comment: Thanks I got github working I had configured `Artifactory` as Module provider. Now only Bitbucket on prime is remaining. for bitbucket I have configured `Stash / Bitbuket Private` as module provider. Still when I try to fetch module It gives 404 without trying to fetch it from bitbucket-go remote repo in artifactory.

Comment: Unfortunately, BitBucket and GitHub on prem are not supported yet. But do upgrade to Artifactory 6.10 or up, there was some fixes to Go focusing on the UX of those flows and more...